# iPhone settings preferences like the Mail app

Tags: iphone

I want to create some settings much like the Mail settings within the Settings app. These allow you to add mail accounts. I want to add accounts in settings for my app and have the new account appear in settings just like the mail app does. I haven't been able to figure out how they did it. How is this done and anyone got a sample plist file they could provide?

Answer (score 1):

You need a settings bundle.

Here is Apple doc for it: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html

Comment: I don't think that answers Regbuntu's question. He basically wants to add more customizable behavior into the settings area. Third party apps only appear to be able to specify the settings layout via configuration parameters in the Root.plist file. You can't inject any code into the process to make it more dynamic. It looks like Apple is using private APIs to manage settings for Mail.app and wifi e.g..

Comment: I already added a settings bundle, but I can't figure out how to make my settings behave like the Mail app's settings. I want to be able to create multiple accounts like you can in the mail app. Apple is always saying that they give us the "same" tools etc that they use, are they using something different like a private API as Joost suggested?